# javascript alert with different value

Tags: javascript, html

i have a link with the value of Active and Offline..

```
while($s = mysql_fetch_array($strength))
{
?>
<a href="updateperiode.php?id=<?php echo $s['periode_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirmReset()">
<?php if($s['status'] == 'Active')
{
?>
<span class="badge_style b_online">Active</span>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<span class="badge_style b_offline">Offline</span>
<?php
}
?>
</a>
<?php } ?>
```

what i want to do is,, if the value is Active, and the user is click it, the alert with pop out.. and says do you want to deactive, and if the value is offline, when the user click, the alert will says do you want to activate ..

and my javascript is like this..

```
<script>
    function confirmReset() {
   var div = document.getElementById("div");
   var span = div.getElementsByTagName("span");

   if(span.innerHTML == 'Active')
   {
        var question = confirm("Are you sure want to deactive?");
   } 
   else 
   {
        var question = confirm("Are you sure want to activate?");
   }

    if(question){

    return true;


    }else{


    return false;

    }
}
</script>
```

the output is always `Are you sure want to activate?` even though the value is active..

This is my full code..

http://pastebin.com/FteRz6VN

this is the screen..

http://puu.sh/8CyBy.jpg

Comment: console.log(span.innerHTML);  print this and see in the console, what's coming?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
 <?php
    $i = 0;
    while($s = mysql_fetch_array($strength))
    {
    ?>
    <a href="updateperiode.php?id=<?php echo $s['periode_id']; ?>" onclick="return confirmReset('<?php echo 'status'.$i ?>')">
    <?php if($s['status'] == 'Active')
    {
    ?>
    <span class="badge_style b_online"  id="status<?php echo $i ?>">Active</span>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <span class="badge_style b_offline"  id="status<?php echo $i ?>">Offline</span>

    }
    ?>
    </a>
    <?php $i++; } ?>
    <script>
     function confirmReset(id) {
       var statusDiv = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
       if(statusDiv == "Active"){
            var question = confirm("Are you sure want to deactive?");
       } else {
            var question = confirm("Are you sure want to activate?");
       }
       if(question){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: the output is still the same,,

Comment: can you please send me your code file and screen shot because its working fine from my side

Comment: how can i send to you?? by email?? @anant

Comment: yes you can send me on email. anantprajapati111@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Change the `span` variable:

```
var span = div.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to solve this issue very easily following is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".badge_style").click(function(){
var isActive = $(this).html();
if(isActive == "Active"){
...Do what you want to do if active
alert("do you want to activate!");
}else{
... else part
}

});

});
```

no need to call confirmReset function